How to create hyperlinks in Plain TeX that points to exact positions of labels in another file?
Problem
Cross-file hyperlinks always bring me the first page of another file, while I expect the links to bring me to the exact label position (or text) in the target file.
Reproduction Steps
Environment:

TeX version: Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)
Operating system: Linux distro, Debian 12 bookworm x86_64.

Start:
Suppose that I have a file one.tex with hyperlink labels/targets:
Links to label
{\catcode`\#=11
 \special{html:<a href="#one">}one\special{html:</a>}}
{\catcode`\#=11
 \special{html:<a href="#two">}two\special{html:</a>}}
{\catcode`\#=11
 \special{html:<a href="#three">}three\special{html:</a>}}

Label
{\catcode`\#=11
 \special{html:<a name="one">}one\special{html:</a>}}

\vfil \break
Label
{\catcode`\#=11
 \special{html:<a name="two">}two\special{html:</a>}}

\vfil \break
Label
{\catcode`\#=11
 \special{html:<a name="three">}three\special{html:</a>}}

\bye

After compiling with $ tex one.tex; dvipdfm one.dvi or $ xetex one.tex, I open with mupdf one.pdf. The intra-file links at the top works fine.
Now, suppose that I want to link to these labels from another file two.tex:
Link to label
{\catcode`\#=11
 \special{html:<a href="one.pdf#one">}one\special{html:</a>}}
{\catcode`\#=11
 \special{html:<a href="one.pdf#two">}two\special{html:</a>}}
{\catcode`\#=11
 \special{html:<a href="one.pdf#three">}three\special{html:</a>}}

\bye

After compiling with the same procedure as above, and opening it in mupdf, clicking the links always bring me to the first page of one.pdf. I'd expect link two brings me to page 2/label 2 of one.pdf. And the same goes for link three. (Inter-file links fail)
Is there a way to accomplish my objective in Plain TeX? Or do I have to resort to some particular PDF extensions? Thanks!
Non-solutions
I've read these, but they're not solutions to this problem:

Hyperlinks in plain TeX
Plain TeX and different hyperlink styles in dvi and pdf

LaTeX:

Can you have hyperlinks to locations in different PDFs?
Creating a link to a specific page of another pdf file


I don't think the hypertex specials (with html:) support GoToR links, you would need a full url instead. You will probably need a \special{pdf: bann <<... >>} see the hxetex.def file of hyperref and its \hyper@linkfile implementation.

@UlrikeFischer Thanks for the pointer! I'll look into it
